# Different Node version Global installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

How can i install two different node version 
in this case version 0.10.32 and 8.9.4 (LTS)

when i try using n or nvm to install different version of node and 
then used the following command

```
npm list
```

i am getting the following error after changing to lower version i.e 0.10.32

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-
   client/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:6
   let url
   ^^^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
   at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-
   registry-client/lib/access.js:5:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: @frikkievb issue is on mac , installation was done using brew `brew install node` it downloaded the latest node module i.e is 9.4.0

Comment: Do you want to have two different NodeJS versions, or is it a question about how it is possible that it happend?

Comment: @Anuga i have a requirement where i need to work on either of the version , so i actually need both version running in my system

Comment: Not really recommended, but if you want to and need to, you can use NVM.
https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

Comment: @Anuga hi it actually worked with nvm , but is there a condition that it does not work with n module (Node version management) and it works with nvm also nvm seems to have issue or may be its like that , so i installed pm2 when i was in version 8.9.4 and when i switched back to 0.10.32 then pm2 list throws the a error  me `-bash: pm2: command not found` , this used to show in n module correctly

Comment: might haft to install pm2 under 0.10.32.

Comment: @Anuga it actually worked when i installed pm2 globally in both versions , do you know what could be the reason behind this , using n module(as version management for node) this issue was not there , you install pm2 in any version and does show's up

Comment: No idea, I use different virtual machines for different nodes/npms :(